# Entity Framework, Get table data of any EntityType object as DataGrid can show its columns and data

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have have a method like this in my `WPF` program:

```
void ShowTableInDataGrid(EntityType myEntityType)
{
    var tableName = myEntityType.Name;
    var result = _context.Database.
                 SqlQuery<dynamic>("SELECT * FROM dbo." + tableName).ToList();

    DataGridMain.ItemsSource = result;
}
```

It load data from database base on `TableName` by `EntityFramework` but dose not show any data in `DataGridMain` control. `DataGridMain` create its columns automatically base on entity class info assigned as list to `ItemsSource`.

Now for example **if i change the `dynamic` to `Customer`:**

```
SqlQuery<Customer>("SELECT * FROM dbo." + tableName).ToList();
```

**And `TableName` be `Customer`, then `DataGridMain` show columns and data very well**.

But i have over 100 different table and i don't know which table info will be passed to the `ShowTableInDataGrid` method at design time then i should write over 100 case (One case for each Table in the EF) to handle this problem like this:

```
void ShowTableInDataGrid(EntityType myEntityType)
{
    var tableName = myEntityType.Name;

    //....

    switch (selectedEntity.Name)
    {
        case "Customer":
        {
            result = _db.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>("SELECT * FROM dbo." + selectedEntity.Name).ToList();
                break;
        }

        case "Book":
        {
            result = _db.Database.SqlQuery<Book>("SELECT * FROM dbo." + selectedEntity.Name).ToList();
                break;
        }
        .
        .
        .
        . // OVER 100 CASE !!!
        .
        .
        .
        default:
        {
            MessageBox.Show("New Case Needed!");
            break;
        }
    }

    DataGridMain.ItemsSource = result;
}
```

**My question is:**

Is there any way to prevent this switch cases??? I think this way is Hard-Code and very static. I hate this way..

---

*Base of this works: I want show `EF` tables in my `Comobox` and Show it in `DataGrid` when i select one table from `Combobox`. Currently my `Combobox` works well and `DataGrid` is the problem.*

Comment: What you want may be the `DbSet` representing all entities in a set. So you can try this instead `result = _db.Set(Type.GetType(myEntityType.FullName))` - just that line, no more switch-case. Also it works only if your entity types are declared in the current assembly, otherwise you need to get the type via its Assembly and its FullName another way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it seems to not complain about it, but don't have the full setup to test it out.

```
void ShowTableInDataGrid(System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EntityType myEntityType) {
        var tableName = myEntityType.GetType();
        var result = _context.Database.
                     SqlQuery<myEntityType.GetType()> ("SELECT * FROM dbo." + tableName).ToList();

        DataGridMain.ItemsSource = result;
    }
```

Comment: you don't need to test this, it of course won't work. The placement of `<T>` is some design time class name passed it, not an instance of anything.